# How does the sin function from numpy work?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

A few months ago I finally figured out how to make sound files with a python program. But I'm having issues. The code relies on a function called 'sin' from the module 'numpy'. Here's the code I made:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

sps=44100

freq=440.0

duration=5

amp=0.02

eachSampleNumber=np.arange(duration*sps)
waveform=np.sin(2*np.pi*eachSampleNumber*freq/sps)
waveformQuiet=waveform*amp
waveformIntegers=np.int16(waveformQuiet*32767)
write('first_sine_wave.wav',sps,waveformIntegers)
```

The issue is strange things happen if I do certain things. If I change the length of the sound, it alters the pitch. Also, if I try to concatenate sounds together (which I've been doing by simply adding the resulting arrays together), the resulting sound file will instead have the two sounds overlapping each other rather than coming one after another. For instance, if I add two sounds together that are each a second long, instead of creating a two-second sound file with the two notes played one after the other, I'll get a one-second sound file with the two notes being played simultaneously.

I don't know how sin waves are actually made by hand, and I can't find documentation revealing to me the formula this function is using. I also don't understand why concatenating two arrays together in this instance results in an array of the same length. Printing out the resulting array, it looks normal to me. I don't understand why anything is working the way it is.

As for how I've been making sound files, I've just been manually changing the variables within the code itself and running the program. Because of the issues I'm having, I haven't gotten around to making a proper executable yet. I was hoping to eventually use this to make my own music maker program.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be more of a math question than a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

you want to check out how arrays work in `numpy` rather than the `sin` function.  adding two arrays (with `+`) does different things depending on the shape of arrays according to the ["broadcasting" rules in numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).  if you want a new array with values from one followed by values from another then you want to [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) things

I've rearranged your code a bit in a way that might make things clearer:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io.wavfile import write

# set a global sample rate as this is fixed across one wav file
sample_rate = 44100

# define a function to return a tone at a given frequency and duration
def make_sinewave(duration, freq):
    time = np.arange(0, duration, 1/sample_rate)
    return np.sin(time * (2*np.pi*freq))

# join several tones together
waveform = np.concatenate([
    make_sinewave(1.0, 440) * 0.5,
    make_sinewave(0.5, 880) * 0.1,
    make_sinewave(0.7, 660) * 0.2,
])

# convert to appropriate data type
waveformIntegers = np.int16(waveform * 32767)

# write out
write('first_sine_wave.wav', sample_rate, waveformIntegers)
```

Answer (score 1):

> If I try to concatenate sounds together (which I've been doing by **simply adding the resulting arrays** together), the resulting sound file will instead have the two sounds overlapping each other rather than coming one after another.

With NumPy, addition of arrays is very different than addition with Python lists. The former does elementwise addition, whereas the latter concatenates.

```
>>> arr = np.arange(5)
>>> arr + arr
array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])

>>> lst = list(range(5))
>>> lst + lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To achieve what you want you need to use specialized functions.

```
>>> np.concatenate([arr, arr], axis=0)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

>>> np.hstack([arr, arr])
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Well, that solves one problem. But why is it that if I change the duration, the pitch also changes? How can I change the duration of a sound without it altering the pitch? Do I need to make some kind of loop to just concatenate the array x number of times? And yes, I know how to make a both a while and a for loop (I have a certificate in python, though I've been teaching myself pygame and any other modules I've found that I need for games)